# How much did the TRS-80 Model III weigh?

Tags: trs-80-model-iii

How much did the Radio Shack TRS-80 Model III weigh? I imagine it must have been quite a lot, with the computer, monitor, power supply and up to 2 disk drives all in the same case, but I haven't been able to find an actual number anywhere.

Comment: Good question, gotta drive to my storage to check. There might be some variations due diverging accessories.

Comment: I don't think it was that heavy. It only has a 12" B&W CRT which would be most of the weight.

Comment: I'll bet it's pretty lightweight compared to a PET. The Mac G3 AIO "Molar" is the heaviest I've felt.

Comment: Do you mean the dry-weight of a fully laden TRS-80? ;)

Comment: I have one in the garage, will try to remember to weigh it tonight.

Comment: I carried one of these home from a friends house (she gave it to me) by hand, walking it about a mile, at the age of 13. At that time, it seemed like it weighed 100 pounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An old acquaintence of mine that I used to buy a fair bit of kit from (and hope to again, possibly a Model 4 if he can source one) informs me that the TRS-80 Model III clocks in at about 20kg, boxed up. That's about 44lbs for those quaint people not wholly converted to metric :-)

I can't imagine the box and packing itself would be much more than a kilo or so, so I'd put the weight of the computer itself in the high teens.